# How can I use Activity page instead of Fragment for Android Page swiping?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, android-fragmentactivity

it works fine for fragments swiping page. But I want to spipe my pages using activity. So please help me how can I rewrite the following code for Activity class?

```
private void initialisePaging() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AboutFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ServiceFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,ProcessFragment.class.getName()));
    mPagerAdapter =new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}
```

But I want like this,

```
List<ActionBarActivity> ac=new Vector<ActionBarActivity>();
ac.add(ActionBarActivity.INPUT_SERVICE(this, AboutActivity.class.getName()));
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

this code is not correct. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,there is no regular way to use activity instead of fragment in ViewPager.
Fragment has nearly the same ability as activity, why you don't use Fragment ?

Comment: I am newbie, How can I use Actionbar in Fragment?

Comment: `getActivity().getActionBar()` gives you the activity's actionbar, also if you want to inflate a different menu then you can override the `void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` , if you want to handle menu item clicks then override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Comment: Hi,I know how bad you want to make a App quickly.but first you still need to learn some basic knowlege about android,Just buy a book and read through it.You will find a way to use fragment to implement your requirement instead of activity.and you will know why you can't use activity.